# How to stop Excel "trying to connect to <my file server>" and make it just save the file?

Tags: windows, networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Client: Excel 2007 on Windows 7. 
Server: Samba 4.1.17+dfsg-2+deb8u2 on Debian Jessie/AMD64

When opening files from a network location:

- Excel takes a very long time to start opening the file (upwards of 30 seconds)
- Choosing file save/as causes it to take a similar length of time before it shows the "save as" dialog, during which it shows a dialog box that says "trying to connect to (path from which the file was opened)"
- After choosing a file to save it and before prompting for confirmation that the file type doesn't support all features (e.g. when saving as tab delimited text) there is also a long delay, but no dialog box this time.
- The file saves reasonably quickly after the dialog box is dismissed.

I have checked the following:

- Disabled antivirus
- Ping server (responses are fine)
- Ability to access the file regularly via explorer (copying file to/from same location takes <1 second)
- Disabling SMB2 functionality on the client
- Checking for the office file validation update (it isn't installed)
- Ensuring that automatic proxy configuration is disabled in IE settings
- Setting up Excel to automatically trust my network server

None of these has helped the problem.  Are there any other potential solutions to this issue?

Comment: Do other Office or MS programs have a similar problem? What happens if you make a folder Test at the root of the share, and move just one of the excel files into it. Is it still slow?  What extension are the files? (CSV,XLS,XLSX,etc.)

Comment: I haven't tested, and am unfortunately not currently at the site where the problem is happening, but I don't believe other applications are affected.  The files have .xls extension (opening) and .txt (when saving).  I have tested two distinct source files, but both came from the same source (where I believe they were generated by Excel 2003).

Comment: There have been multiple problems with .xls with my work.  Basically they have been security related since a .xls can have a macro inside. Issues have come from security vendor (box on network that is constantly checking for virus), microsoft (not trusting .xls and then not trusting network shares) and then our fileshare app vendor. One solution was to recast them as .xlsx Microsoft has a tool that does it, or have the staff do it as part of a general clean up. (80% of the files were no longer needed in one case)

Comment: None of the 3 sources of issues wanted to admit they had introduced a change that caused this. It took a lot of effort in all 3 times I was involved to find out the source.  Try all the combinations, (.xls, .xlsx) local hard drive, usb mounted drive, network share, Macs, and look at the patterns.  Some like the "invisible" infosec box had time frame patterns as off hours had less overall traffic so it was a lot quicker. But once identified, solutions were generally able to be gotten